# How to verify mask letter in email using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I will get random email id in my confirmation page.That should be in below format. a****a@gmail.com
Can I verify email format in selenium?

```
<div class="cart-wrapper grid-container">
<div class="grid-40">
<div class="cart-confirmation-copy">
<p class="cart-confirmation-email">A***A@gmail.COM</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ***Can I verify email format in selenium?*** ....verify what ? the resulting mask? the mail server? the resulting value?

Comment: email format should be a******c@gmail.com. This email id should be displayed in web application.I need to verify email id masked and mentioned format too

Answer (score 0):

beside using selenium use JavaMail to validate the email format. You just need to `getText()` from selenium then pass it to the function

Using the [official java email](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) package is the easiest:

```
public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
   boolean result = true;
   try {
      InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
      emailAddr.validate();
   } catch (AddressException ex) {
      result = false;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Can we check character masked in email?

Comment: No we can't, it's just mask and selenium will retrieve same for you as present on DOM. Selenium can't go beyond your business logic applied on your application. But what you can do is using replace method or change the * with something else before passing the string to the function

Comment: can we replace  asdfg@gmail.com as a***g@gmail.com

Comment: yes you can. You need write the logic to convert it . and above lib should also support it as it shown an valid email as per http://verifalia.com/validate-email